# How to load a config file in Spring which is not in the resources folder

Tags: spring, config

In my Spring application, the application.xml has

```
context:property-placeholder location="classpath:configuration.properties"
```

using which I am able to run the java code

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

However, this requires me to have the configuration.properties file to be in the resources folder. Instead I want to externalize the file from the application. How can I configure the application.xml to load an external config file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try `file:applicationContext.xml`. That will try to load the file from the current directory.

I suggest to use `file:config/applicationContext.xml`. Then you can use a config folder for all such files.

Now you will need a startup script that `cd`s into the folder where your app is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an absolte path for your requirement

```
context:property-placeholder location="file:/path/to/configuration.properties"
```